# use stored procedure declare tables in crystal report 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2008

I am creating accounting system.But i am in trouble to creating the trial balance.So I found this stored procedure from internet that can make trail balance But trouble is that how i can used this type of stored produce in crystal report using visual studio 2008 4.0 net c#. Because in this stored procedure table is creating and some data are inserting as wall

```
USE [data_base]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




ALTER procedure [dbo].[gettrial]
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime
AS
declare @tab1 table
(
debit decimal(18,2),
credit decimal(18,2),
account varchar(20),
balance decimal(18,2),
accountname varchar(50)
)
insert into @tab1
select sum(dr),sum(cr),jdetail.accountno,sum(dr)-sum(cr),accountname 
from jdetail
join account on account.accountno=jdetail.accountno
where date>=@startdate and date<=@enddate
group by jdetail.accountno,account.accountname

select accountname as 'AccountTitle' ,account as 'Account No.', 
'Debit'=case when sign(balance)=1
then balance 
end,
'Credit'=case when sign(balance)=-1
then balance*-1
end
from @tab1
--where balance<>0
ORDER BY 'Credit','Debit' asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the above mentioned procedure as the data source of your report and only the result set will be used for displaying the data in your report. The temporary tables used is the procedure will exists in the scope of the current session and it will not affect the working of the report